# Counting total number of pages across multiple PDF files on the Windows' Powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, awk

I'm trying to write a single script on the Windows' Powershell so I can know the total number of pages across various pdf files in the same directory. However, I'm not getting the intended results. Here's my script:

```
$files = l .
$result = 0
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) 
{
    $fileName = $files[$i].FullName
    if ($fileName.EndsWith(".pdf"))
    {
         pdfinfo.exe $fileName | findstr.exe "Pages:*" | awk '{$result += $2} {print $result}'
    }
}
```

Current results (Individual number of pages):

```
20 
19 
10 
16 
18 
14 
9  
29 
24 
28 
16 
30 
32 
21 
13 
17
```

Expected results:

```
20
39
49
65
83
...
...
...
316
```

Or just the final value:

```
316
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just to make clear `pdfinfo` isn't a tool which comes with Windows/PowerShell**
Windows and Linux versions can be downloaded from
https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html

If using PowerShell I'd stay with it as much as possible:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\07\SO_1446208.ps1

$folder = 'C:\Test'
$Total = $Files = 0

foreach($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.pdf)){
    $Pages = (pdfinfo $File.FullName | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=Pages:\s*)\d+').Matches.Value
    $Total += $Pages
    $Files++
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PdfFile = $File.Name
        Pages   = $Pages
    }
}
"`nTotalNumber of pages: {0} in {1} files" -f $Total,$Files
```

Sample output (the whole `[PSCustomObject]` just for reference)

```
> Q:\Test\2019\06\07\SO_1446208.ps1

PdfFile                      Pages
-------                      -----
2014-02-25_Allwinner A80.pdf 1
test.pdf                     4

TotalNumber of pages: 5 in 2 files
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not very familiar with the powershell syntax, so I would still like to know why my version isn't working

Comment: I think `awk '{$result += $2}` will append strings, and not do an addition.