# pdfinfo.exe isn't working on Powershell

Tags: windows, pdf, document-management, powershell-5.0

I am trying to do the PowerShell script outlined in the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1446208/counting-total-number-of-pages-across-multiple-pdf-files-on-the-windows-powersh#).  The question and solution reference "pdfinfo.exe" and "pdfinfo".  When I research this, it looks like it should be packaged in some versions of PowerShell but not others.  On my machine, the command is not recognized.  How might I get this package without downloading a corrupt or malicious file?  I am trying to get a total page count of multiple pdf files within a folder structure.

I am using Windows 10 and Powershell / ISE version 5.1.17763.503

Thanks!

Comment: [pdf - Windows equivalent for Unix's pdfinfo - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263643/windows-equivalent-for-unixs-pdfinfo)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have downloaded the files but the command still does not work even after an install of the closed version.  Is there some step I have missed?

Comment: Did you specify the full path of pdfinfo?

Comment: Add pdfinfo to your PATH. See http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: This seems odd, are you absolutely sure this is supposed to work with PowerShell 5.1 instead of PowerShell Core?  From what I can tell [pdfinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfinfo) is a Linux utility, not a Windows utility.

Answer (score 1):

> When I research this, it looks like it should be packaged in some versions of PowerShell but not others.

[pdinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfinfo) is not included with PowerShell on Windows.  It actually isn't a Windows utility.

However, a Windows port does exist, [here](https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdfinfo-man.html).  Your script will not work without it.

> On my machine, the command is not recognized. How might I get this package without downloading a corrupt or malicious file?

I cannot speak to the legitimacy of the source I have provided.  I am only answering this question due to the mistaken belief it's supposed to be installed and/or otherwise included with PowerShell.

**The tool in question has nothing to do with PowerShell it is simply a utility being called from a PowerShell script in the answer you linked to.**

Source: [Windows equivalent for Unix's pdfinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263643/windows-equivalent-for-unixs-pdfinfo)